# CakePHP 2.x: BindModel not working in Unit testig

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0

I am checking Unit Testing in CakePHP2.

**OrdersController**

```
$this->Discount->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'Coupon' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'discount_id',
            'join' => 'INNER',
        ),
    ),
));  

$options = array();
$options['conditions'] = [
    'Discount.status' => 1,
    'Coupon.status' => 1,
];
$all_discounts = $this->Discount->find('all', $options);
```

**OrdersControllerTest**

```
public function testRestaurantDomain()
{
    $this->testAction('/orders/index');
}
```

I am getting `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Coupon.status' in 'where clause'` error.

When I comment out `Coupon.status` condition then it is working fine. So what am I missing here for bindmodel to work with Unit Testing?

Comment: Check if your fixture has that field.

Comment: @burzum I am not using fixture here, but when I add `joins` in `$options` array then it's working fine. But with bindModel it's not working.